# Add color filter to Tk.Label

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have a `tk.Label` object with an image (via `tk.Label(self.root,image='image.png')`) and want to add a color filter to it, i.e. make the image more red. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the image with PIL, and save it as a new file. In Tkinter, you can use `PhotoImage(file="file.png")` to use the image as a button:

```
# importing image object from PIL
from PIL import ImageOps, Image
import PIL.Image


# creating an image object
img = Image.open(r"test.png").convert("L")

# image colorize function
img = ImageOps.colorize(img, black="red", white="white")

# save the image as new.png
img.save("new.png")

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# set the img1 variable as the image we just created
img1 = PhotoImage(file="new.png")
b = Button(image=img1)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why saving it? Directly use `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` on it.

Comment: Thank you! After a little bit of experimenting, I found that img=ImageOps.colorize(img,black='black',white='salmon') does the job for me. Out of curiosity and since I couldn't find an answer in the documentation, the r in front of 'test.png' means the image is opened in read only mode? Or what is it?

Comment: No, that's to say "regular string", so it doesn't do things like a new line in \n.